# Query statement in Expression Web

Tags: sql-server-2008, microsoft-expression-web

Sir, the following statement in Expression Web is work for count one criteria 
`SELECT COUNT(Rly) AS CR FROM SPAD WHERE Rly='CR'`.

Now the issue is that if more than one criteria is required in same column, for example `Count(Rly) AS ER FROM SPAD WHERE Rly='ER'`

What statement will be required?
Please help.

Comment: Where does Expression Web come into this? Is this not purely SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count both values:

```
SELECT COUNT(Rly) AS TheCount FROM SPAD WHERE Rly IN ('CR', 'ER')
```

To count separately in one go:

```
SELECT COUNT(Rly) AS TheCount, Rly 
FROM SPAD
WHERE Rly IN ('CR', 'ER')
GROUP BY Rly
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr. gbn.  Sir, by doing so I got the result as heading TheCount,Rly and the data in below as 2, CR & 2, ER. But my requirement is Rly in header like CR, ER, ECR & the count in below the header respectively. e.g.